# Gwt prolem with loading map!

Tags: gwt, dictionary, loading

I'm new in GWT and I made some simple projects and in the last one I use google maps api.
The problem is that there is no result when I wrote the code and the script and add the libraries and I have problems to locate the source of the nocache.js file. Can somebody tell me how to do a simple web site with google maps api (gwt - maps).

Answer (score 1):

Try starting with a [tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/MapsGettingStarted) they provide.